# How To Create an Algorithm For Continous Flow of Objects Without Any Gaps Or Overlaps?

Tags: algorithms

I need to create a mathematical solution or algorithm for the following real life problem:

```
     F     E     D     C    B    A    Output
T1   _     _     _     _    _    _    _    
T2   _     _     _     _    _    _    _
T3   _     _     _     _    _    _    _
T4   _     _     _     _    _    _    _
T5   _     _     _     _    _    _    _
T6   _     _     _     _    _    _    _
.
.
.
```

T is a clock ticking at 1 sec intervals and the underlines flow continuously from left to right. Every tick, I need to drop ONE letter on the underlines. Few rules must be followed for dropping the letters: 1) I can't drop/overlap letters on top of each other 2) the output needs to have a continuous (no gaps) flow of letters. Example,

```
     F     E     D     C    B    A    Output
T1   F     _     _     _    _    _    _    
T2   _     F     _     _    _    _    _
T3   _     E     F     _    _    _    _
T4   _     _     E     F    _    _    _
T5   _     _     D     E    F    _    _
T6   _     _     _     D    E    F    _
T7   _     _     _     C    D    E    F
T8   _     _     D     _    C    D    E (Problem Here! A gap is created!)
T9   _     _     _     D    _    C    D
T10   _     _     _     _    D    _   C
T11   _     _     _     _    _    D   _ (Gap. Not acceptable.)
```

How do I approach in solving this problem?

EDIT 1: There will always be 6 letter. There is no specific pattern of letters. I just need a continuous output.

EDIT 2: I also need an equal or close to equal effort of letter distribution. Lets say, each letter is dropped 1/6th of the time. An optimum distribution of letters at the output.

EDIT 3: You can drop the same letter twice in a row if you wish, but that won't give me a nice letter distribution.. Also, at every T time, a letter can be dropped.

EDIT 4: The action is: Every T, shift to the right, then drop a letter.

Comment: I don't understand the conditions yet. Please edit the question to show us a few more acceptable solutions (f there are any), and perhaps one that's unacceptable even though no letters overlap. Will you always have $6$ letters? If not, can you show us some examples for three or four letters too?

Comment: OK now we know there are always $6$ letters. Please edit the question to show us some other possible solutions. Since you seem to have one solution already, what do you want an algorithm to do? It's not clear what can or must happen after time about $13$, when it looks as if all the letters will have been used once and fallen off the end.

Comment: I want to continuously drop letters without creating gaps in the output: F E _ C D E F (the underline is not acceptable. It means there was a gap in the sequence)

Comment: Can you drop the same letter twice? Also you drop no letter at time T2 in your example. Can you only drop a single letter? Otherwise you will not be able to regain access to the leftmost letters later on, ie. once you have skipped $n$ time steps you have rendered $n$ letters useless.

Comment: - Yes you can drop the same letter twice.
- At T2, I didnt drop a letter was just an example. You can drop any letter at T2. Every T, you can drop a letter.

Comment: Then the algorithm is straight forward. If you drop a letter, you HAVE to drop letter $n$ from the left (zero indexed) where $n$ counts the total number of time steps you have skipped.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution (not sure if this is an optimum solution) by trial and error:

```
    F   E   D   C   B   A   Output
T1  _   _   D   C   _   _   _
T2  _   E   _   D   C   _   _
T3  F   _   E   _   D   C   _
T4  _   F   _   E   _   D   C       (No Letter Dropped Here)
T5  _   _   F   _   E   A   DC
T6  _   _   _   F   B   E   ADC
T7  _   _   D   C   F   B   EADC        (T1 Event Repeats Here)
T8  _   E   _   D   C   F   BEADC
T9  F   _   E   _   D   C   FBEADC
T10 _   F   _   E   _   D   CFBEADC     (No Letter Dropped Here)
T11 _   _   F   _   E   A   DCFBEADC
T11 _   _   _   F   B   E   ADCFBEADC
T12 _   _   D   C   F   B   EADCFBEADC  (T1 Event Repeats Here
and so on
```

Now, I need a way to represent this mathematically so I am able to solve similar problem with different number of columns (letters from A to Z for example). Thanks!

Note: with even number of columns, two letters are dropped at the same time (T1, T7, T12) and a single drop is skipped (T4, T10). With Odd number of columns, I don't think these two things occur.